# Unable to create WebGL context, unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I have a canvas on my webpage stored at a negative z index.
With a click of a button, I want the unity game to load using loading the unity script as a promise.
The promise executes perfectly but after the script loads I get an error

```
Creating WebGL 2.0 context.
unity.loader.js:1 Unable to create WebGL context.
unity.loader.js:1 exception thrown: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getParameter'),TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getParameter')
    at _glGetString (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:248153)
    at http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.wasm:wasm-function[29563]:0x8cc821
    at http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.wasm:wasm-function[25931]:0x82d2c6
    at Module._main (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:299245)
    at callMain (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:364104)
    at doRun (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:364664)
    at run (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:364836)
    at runCaller (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:363763)
    at Object.removeRunDependency (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:16089)
    at http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:1948
    at doCallback (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:92358)
    at done (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:92512)
    at transaction.oncomplete (http://localhost:5500/scripts/unity/Build/unity.framework.js:3:85617)
```

I have a background particle effect that runs using requestAnimationFrame() and ends just before the unity script starts loading using cancelAnimationFrame()

I can't find much on the internet

Comment: Well. Does it work with the basic normal webgl loader?

Comment: @BugFinder yeah, the index html page that comes with the build makes it run but otherwise no. There's basically a blank canvas on my webpage in the background which i use for background animations. I only want unity to take control of that canvas after the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, after 30 minutes of debugging the problem was that the context of the canvas was set to be 2d, while the unity build was 3d. Created a new canvas element and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Context loss happens with any WebGL build and is not related specifically to Unity.
I couldn't find any details about this issue and fix it without reloading web page.
Most likely this is caused by a limitation on the number of contexts in a browser or the memory for them